# VBA Web Scraping: click on radio buttom

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I need to click on a radio buttom from a web site, I have tried many variants of getelementby... and querySelector without succes.
This is the source line code:

```
<input type="radio" name="incremental" value="0">
```

IE Version 11

Please help.

Comment: Did you try like this `queryselector("input[name='incremental']")`?

Comment: Thank you for answer, it works but there are 2 radio buttoms, in the first one the value is 1 and I need to click in the value 0, this code makes click on the first. I tought on add (1) but it gaves me error.

Comment: queryselectorAll("input[name='incremental']")(1).click

Comment: Thank you very much buddy, I didnt know that it had to be "queryselectorAll", it works wonderfully, genius!.

Comment: I expect QHarr to come across this post. If he is here, you may have a great explanation as to how .querySelector()` works.

Comment: @Topto You should post this as an answer btw. I will happily put some info underneath you can add in. Though it looks like you got it covered!

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @Topto

```
queryselectorAll("input[name='incremental']")(1).click
```